# Exclude partition in Icinga2 check disk [check_disk] not working

Tags: ubuntu, icinga

I'm trying to exclude a partition from `check_disk` command in [Icinga2](https://icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/) and it's not working as expected.

The problem is due to `/snap/core` being recognised as a partition like this.
[image]

So, I've opened the `hosts` file and added `disk_partitions_excluded` from the [documentation](https://icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/10-icinga-template-library/#disk).

```
/* Define disks and attributes for service apply rules in `services.conf`. */
  vars.disks["disk"] = {
    /* No parameters. */
    disk_partitions_excluded  = "/snap/core/*"
  }
  vars.disks["disk /"] = {
    disk_partitions = "/"
  }
```

But even after doing so and restarting `Icinga2` with `systemcl restart icinga2` the error doesn't go away.

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to fix it by checking existing partitions on the system

```
root@icinga2:/etc/icinga2/conf.d# sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME   FSTYPE    SIZE MOUNTPOINT      LABEL
loop0  squashfs   91M /snap/core/6350
loop1  squashfs 89.4M /snap/core/6818
sda               40G
├─sda1             1M
└─sda2 ext4       40G /
sr0             1024M
```

and then explicitly specifying them in the exclude parameter

```
/* Define disks and attributes for service apply rules in `services.conf`. */
  vars.disks["disk"] = {
    /* No parameters. */
    disk_partitions_excluded = ["/snap/core/6350", "/snap/core/6818"]
  }
  vars.disks["disk /"] = {
    disk_partitions = "/"
  }
```

I'm not sure why the wildcard isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to use `disk_ignore_ereg_path`:

```
/* Define disks and attributes for service apply rules in `services.conf`. */
  vars.disks["disk"] = {
    disk_all = true
    disk_ignore_ereg_path = ["/snap/core/.*"]
  }
  vars.disks["disk /"] = {
    disk_partitions = "/"
  }
```

however, `disk_all` has to be set to true to have all other disks monitored.